# Derivative of integral functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

a) Compute the derivative of F(x) :

$F(x) =\int\limits_{sin x}^{x^3} t(t-3) dt$

b) compute the derivative of F(x) :

$F(x)= \int\limits_{x^2}^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt$

My work:

For b)  $\int\limits_{x^2}^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt=F(\sin x)-F(x^2)$

The function $\,\sqrt{1+t^4}\;$ is defined and continuous everywhere, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus , so

$$\int\limits_{x^2}^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt=F(\sin x)-F(x^2)$$

with $\;F\;$ a function s.t. $\,F'(x)=\sqrt{1+x^4}\;$

Thus we get, applying the chain rule:

$$\left(\int\limits_{x^2}^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+t^4}dt\right)'=\left(F(\sin x)-F(x^2)\right)'=\cos xF'(\sin x)-2xF'(x^2) =$$

$$=\cos x\sqrt{1+\sin^4x}-2x\sqrt{1+x^8}$$

Can you help me with a) please. I tried the same use the FTC but i stuck with this function.

Comment: a) F(x) is a constant...

Comment: sorry i edited , i was wrong with the function of a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $g(t)=t(t-3)$,

$$\begin{align}\frac{dF(x)}{dx}&=g(x^3)(x^3)^\prime-g(\sin (x))(\sin (x))^\prime\\&=3x^2g(x^3)-\cos (x)g(\sin (x))\\&=3x^2\cdot x^3(x^3-3)-\cos (x)\sin (x)(\sin (x)-3)\\&=3x^5(x^3-3)-\cos(x)\sin(x)(\sin(x)-3).\end{align}$$

In general, 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t)dt=f(v(x))v^\prime(x)-f(u(x))u^\prime(x).$$

Comment: Excume is it valid the same argument if i have the function $f(x)= \int\limits_{1}^{x^2}\cos(1+\sqrt{t})dt$ ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: really tahnxs..

Answer (score 3):

You can get some idea from the following link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

In general:
$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt \right) = f(x,b(x))\cdot b'(x) - f(x,a(x))\cdot a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f(x，t)}{\partial x}dt$

So the final result for (a) is $3x^5(x^3-3)-sin(x)cos(x)(sin(x)-3)$ as shown by 'mathlove'

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but you use $F$ with two interpreations.

Let $$G' = g$$ and let

$$
F(x) = \int_{x^2}^{\sin x} g(t) dt$$
Here 
$$
g(x) = \sqrt{1+x^4}$$

Then
$$
F(x) = G(\sin x) -G (x^2)
$$
Differentiate
$$
F'(x) = G'(\sin x) \cos(x) - G'(x^2) 2\, x = g(\sin x) \cos x - g(x^2) 2 x \\
= \sqrt{1+\sin^4 x } \cos x - 2 x \sqrt{1+x^8}$$

Comment: ok, thanks and for a) some help please.